# Get string value from Model

Tags: c#

I am having difficulty getting a string value from a model. Instead I am getting a numeric value even after I try to convert the value.

Here is my code

```
var ExitStatus = _repository.GetExitStatusById(emp.StatusId).Result;
response = new GetExitResponse();
response.Exits = new HashSet<EmployeeExitItem>()
{
    new EmployeeExitItem()
    {
          Action = (EExitActions)emp.ActionId,
          EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId,
          ExitId = emp.ExitId,
          KickoffDate = emp.KickoffDate,
          Status = ParseEnum<EExitStatus>(emp.StatusId.ToString()),
          StatusDescription = ParseEnum<EExitStatusDescription>(ExitStatus.StatusDescription.ToString())
    }
};


public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}

public async Task<ExitStatus> GetExitStatusById(int StatusId)
{
    var sql = $"SELECT top 1 * FROM lu.ExitStatus where StatusId = '{StatusId}'";
    await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    var x = await connection.QueryAsync<ExitStatus>(sql);
    return x.FirstOrDefault();
}


public partial class EmployeeExit
{
    public Guid ExitId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime KickoffDate { get; set; }
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [BindNever]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public Guid? OpportunityId { get; set; }
    public int ClaimId { get; set; }

}


using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Digital.HrAssist.Services.Models
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum EExitStatusDescription 
    {
        Started,
        Incomplete,
        Completed,
        Cancelled,
        SubmittedForProcessing
    }
}
```

lu.ExitStatus table attached here
[image: lu exitstatus table]

The problem is that I am getting a number instead of the string value. e.g I want to get "Started" and not 1. This is specifically for the `StatusDescription`

Comment: can you paste your enums defined and parseenum function

Comment: @neeleshbodgal I have added to the question

Comment: You could try [Enum.GetName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @neeleshbodgal would I add this to the public enum EExitStatusDescription file?

Comment: @skydev ignore the last comment. Did you debug your code to check the values?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal yes. I get a `0` instead of `started` for example. Because the `started` is the first value in the list

Comment: StatusDescription = ParseEnum<EExitStatusDescription>(ExitStatus.StatusDescription.ToString()) Is this line compiling. Because property type of  StatusDescription is string and ParseEnum is returning  EExitStatusDescription.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal yes I even get the below when I debug the values coming through

https://imgur.com/a/fTOVj6i

Comment: can u check this https://imgur.com/a/00epz1W

Comment: share your code where you call that you get number?